# TemporalType.Date saving Time in Oracle

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jpa, jboss, jboss7.x

I am having a issue using TemporalType.Date from JPA. It seems to be saving the Time value as well and also picking it from the database when selecting the value in the application. This specifically in Oracle DB

I am using Hibernate Version 4.2.20.Final-redhat-1.
Oracle version is 11.2.0.3.0
JBoss Version 6.4.3.GA
Modules included: jboss-as-jpa-hibernate4-7.5.3.Final-redhat-2 and jboss-as-jpa-hibernate3-7.5.3.Final-redhat-2
Oracle Driver: 12.1.0.2.0

Database Configurations:

SELECT used:

```
select * from nls_database_parameters;
select * from nls_instance_parameters;
select * from nls_session_parameters;
```

Configuration:

```
PARAMETER                      VALUE                                  
------------------------------ ----------------------------------------
NLS_LANGUAGE                   AMERICAN                                 
NLS_TERRITORY                  AMERICA                                  
NLS_CURRENCY                   $                                        
NLS_ISO_CURRENCY               AMERICA                                  
NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS         .,                                       
NLS_CHARACTERSET               AL32UTF8                                 
NLS_CALENDAR                   GREGORIAN                                
NLS_DATE_FORMAT                DD-MON-RR                                
NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE              AMERICAN                                 
NLS_SORT                       BINARY                                   
NLS_TIME_FORMAT                HH.MI.SSXFF AM                           
NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT           DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM                 
NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT             HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR                       
NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT        DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR             
NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY              $                                        
NLS_COMP                       BINARY                                   
NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS           BYTE                                     
NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP            FALSE                                    
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET         AL16UTF16                                
NLS_RDBMS_VERSION              11.2.0.3.0                               

 20 linhas selecionadas 

PARAMETER                      VALUE                                  
------------------------------ ----------------------------------------
NLS_LANGUAGE                   AMERICAN                                 
NLS_TERRITORY                  AMERICA                                  
NLS_SORT                                                                
NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE                                                       
NLS_DATE_FORMAT                                                         
NLS_CURRENCY                                                            
NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS                                                  
NLS_ISO_CURRENCY                                                        
NLS_CALENDAR                                                            
NLS_TIME_FORMAT                                                         
NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT                                                    
NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT                                                      
NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT                                                 
NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY                                                       
NLS_COMP                       BINARY                                   
NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS           BYTE                                     
NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP            FALSE                                    

 17 linhas selecionadas 

PARAMETER                      VALUE                                  
------------------------------ ----------------------------------------
NLS_LANGUAGE                   BRAZILIAN PORTUGUESE                     
NLS_TERRITORY                  BRAZIL                                   
NLS_CURRENCY                   R$                                       
NLS_ISO_CURRENCY               BRAZIL                                   
NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS         ,.                                       
NLS_CALENDAR                   GREGORIAN                                
NLS_DATE_FORMAT                DD/MM/RR                                 
NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE              BRAZILIAN PORTUGUESE                     
NLS_SORT                       WEST_EUROPEAN                            
NLS_TIME_FORMAT                HH24:MI:SSXFF                            
NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT           DD/MM/RR HH24:MI:SSXFF                   
NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT             HH24:MI:SSXFF TZR                        
NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT        DD/MM/RR HH24:MI:SSXFF TZR               
NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY              Cr$                                      
NLS_COMP                       BINARY                                   
NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS           BYTE                                     
NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP            FALSE
```

In MySQL and in SQLServer works just fine, 5.5/5.6 in MySQL and 2008/2012/2014 in SQLServer.

Please, all the help I can get will be precious =D

Thanks.

Comment: What is the type of the column in the table? What date are you saving,  what date do you see in the database, and how?

Comment: Hi, its saving as Column Type DATE, the Hibernate is creating the Tables as such. I am saving the date as an object java.util.Date annotated with TemporalType.DATE in an entity and persisting it in Hibernate. I see the DATE and the TIME in DB by changing the session attributes to show me these values and selecting it from the table AND debugging it on the application.

Comment: The DATE type stores dates, from year to seconds. See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#i1847. Use formatting functions to see the date only as year t month if you want to.

Comment: But TemporalType.DATE annotated in the attribute when creating the DB with hibernate should not control it?

Comment: Hibernate cannot create a new oracle data type. It uses what the database provides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this topic has the answer:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/apps-tech/jdbc-112010-090769.html

HOWEVER, the problem also occours if the DB is Oracle 11g, just have to use the driver Oracle 12.

Thanks for the help.